# Why property lists store only small amount of data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, property-list

I am new in Objective-c and i am trying to understand the concept of property lists. I am reading this article https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html

I am almost clear the concept but this article says that "property lists is good to store small amount of data". But why only good for small amount ? What will happen if i use big amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

A property list is just an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. The file must be read or written as a whole. This means the whole thing is in memory. If you change just one little bit, the entire file must be rewritten.

If you have too much data in the plist, you may run out of memory and the reading and writing becomes inefficient.

When you have lots of data, you rarely need it all in memory at once. And with lots of data, you usually just need to update small bits of data at a time or add new data. At this point there are better options like a database (SQLite or Core Data).

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could store large amounts of data in property lists, but at a certain size it gets unpractical. You need to read the whole property list into memory to work with it. There is no way you can only read the parts you are going to need. That limits you to the amount of memory you have.

Then if you changed some values in your huge property list you will have to write the whole thing out to disk. It is not possible to only write the updated parts.

For example: you have a property list that is an array of 10000 dictionaries and you change a value inside a single dictionary. If you want to save this all 10000 dictionaries will have to be written out to disk, even though 9999 of them didn't change. This can take a lot of time, which is about linear with the number of items, or O(n). That is it takes double the time if there are twice as many items.

If you compare this with a database (like sqlite which can be used by Core Data) you will see that the database only has to write the single changed record, no matter how many there are. So it always takes the same time, independent of how many items there are which is O(1).

It also gets quite hard to work with them. You just have dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers and so on. This might be all the data you need to store, but in memory you usually want to use your own classes. This is another thing property lists can't do. On load you would have to loop through your whole property list to create your model objects, and on save you would have to do the process in reverse. This again is slow, and such code is not much fun to write.

Property lists also are pretty much "Apple only". So if you want to exchange your files with other platforms you have to do more work there to read and write that format. In theory Apple even could change the format.

But if you load your whole file into memory and write it out completely anyways you might as well use large property list files, if you can live with the other limitations.

Comment: Nice description . But i am not understand the highlighted  point `Then if you changed some values in your huge property list you will have to write the whole thing out to disk. It is not possible to only write the updated parts.` Can you explain this more detail? Can you give any example? Thanks.

Comment: Added an explanation for this, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Sven to answer my question. Can you suggest any video tutorial that explain limitations of plist. I have seen many tutorial but they only explain what is plist and how to use that but didn't tell limitations.